# Why isn't move_only_function's call operator const?

Tags: c++, std-function

`std::function`'s call operator is `const` because it merely calls a function, and doesn't modify any of its members. Why isn't `std::move_only_function`'s function call operator `const` as with `std::function`'? What members does it need to change? I'm using MSVC's `std::move_only_function`.

Comment: This is a C++23 function.  Remember that C++23 has not actually been released yet.  Things might change.

Comment: `move_only_function` intends to preserve the original callable‘s cv ref and `noexcept` qualifier, so its call operator is *conditional* `const`.

Comment: @TimRoberts: Absent wholly implausible procedural issues, no more technical changes will be made before C++23 is published (although retroactive defect reports are always a possibility).